# Can I visualize the content of a datasets.Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, huggingface-datasets

I am using the Huggingface `datasets` library to load a dataset from a pandas dataframe.
The code is something similar to this:

```
from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b":[1]})
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
```

Everything went smoothly, however, I wanted to double check the content of the loaded `Dataset`. I was looking for something similar to a `df.head()` like we have in Pandas, but I found nothing on the official [Huggingface documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.2.1/loading_datasets.html). Is there a way to "read" even partially the content of the loaded dataset?

Doing a simple `print(dataset)` does not shows the content, but only some high level information:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['a', 'b'],
    num_rows: 1
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simpler than you think. Just do

```
print(dataset[i])
```

where `i` is the number of the row (first is 0).

The output will be a dictionary with the features as keys and the content of the row as values.

```
print(dataset[0])

<<< {
"a": [1],
"b": [1]
}
```

Comment: Ahh I feel dumb now, it was easier than expected. I can use slicing, nice!